# UNIX open multiple windows and pass login/password

Tags: unix, sunos

Straight to the point; I'd like to create a script in UNIX to open two windows at a specific location on the screen, enter in username and password (which would be given by the user as an argument) and then execute another script.

I'd like to know if this is possible and if so; where should I look?

I'm new to UNIX, but am quite familiar with scripting and programming.

---

EDIT after thb and notfed responded

I am currently running SunOS 5.6 on OS X

Comment: It really depends what OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the location of the windows, review X(7) -- that is, type the command `man 7 X` at the terminal and review the result -- and scroll down that man page to the section *GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS,* if your version of the man page has such a section.  In brief, to have the program `xfoo` open its window with a size of 200 horizontally and 160 vertically, with its upper left corner at coordinates (40, 100), give the command `xfoo -geometry 200x160+40+100`.

This may not be a complete answer to your question, since you prudently have not given full details, but one suspects that it will set you on the right track, so to speak.

Regarding your authentication question, the crypt(3) manpage and its *SEE ALSO* section might help.  For more advanced handling, see Libpam, where PAM stands for Pluggable Authentication Modules.

Answer (score 0):

If the two windows are **Xterms**, then there's an easy way to do this;

Note this is from a `ksh` script, but should work in `bash`

```
## This is how big  (how many columns & rows)  your Xterm will be
GEOM0=198x20
GEOM1=98x45

## Colors
COLOR="-bg black -fg white -cr red"

## Xterm Options (See Man page)
XOPTS="+ah +ai -b 2 -cb +cn -j -ls -rw -aw -si +sk" 

## Scroll-back Buffer
SCRLB="9999"

## Commands to execute (you could put an SSH command here)
CMD0="-e /bin/gtail -F /var/adm/messages"

CMD1="-e /bin/gtail -F /var/log/secure"

TITLE="-title Something Clever Here "

TERMBIN=/usr/openwin/bin/xterm

# PLACEMENT
# We specify where we want the window to pop-up by adding "+#+#" to the GEOM.
################################################################################
## Top-Left corner (For my monitor, that's "+2+2")
${TERMBIN} ${XOPTS} -sl ${SCRLB} -fn 6x10 ${COLOR} -geometry ${GEOM0}+2+2 ${TITLE} ${CMD0} &

## Top-Center (For my monitor, that's "+2+233")
${TERMBIN} ${XOPTS} -sl ${SCRLB} -fn 6x10 ${COLOR} -geometry ${GEOM1}+2+233 ${TITLE} ${CMD1} &
```